# VB.NET Posting via HTTP; Build PHP Query

Tags: php, vb.net, post

I am trying to make a post to a website and the site uses the following template:

```
 curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://api.upcdatabase.org/submit/curl.php',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'upc' => '0000000000000',
        'mrsp' => '0.00',
        'apikey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE',
        'title' => 'Title of product',
        'alias' => 'Title alias',
        'description' => 'Optional lengthy description of product.',
        'unit' => 'Per case'
))));
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have found this site to help form the POST.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-27

How do I make the query for the array with the variables upc, mrsp, apikey, title... etc so that I can post it to the site?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us the code you that you struggle with. Do you get any error?

Comment: I tried Dim postData As String = "upc=71928366059,apikey=xxxx,title=TOMATO SAUCE,description=TOMATO SAUCE"

Comment: Add the full code to the question. The above code definitely is not enough to see what you try to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is probably that your post data is using commas as the separator instead of ampersand. This code works, I got "OK" response:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://api.upcdatabase.org/submit/curl.php")
    req.Method = "POST"
    Dim http As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(req, HttpWebRequest)
    http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    Dim postData As String = "upc=0111222333449&apikey=YOU_CANT_SEE_MY_KEY&title=TOMATO SAUCE&description=TOMATO SAUCE&mrsp=1.23&unit=Per Case"
    Dim requestBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    req.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length
    Dim reqStream As System.IO.Stream = http.GetRequestStream()
    reqStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length)
    reqStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = http.GetResponse()
    Dim respStream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim rdr As System.IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(respStream)
    Dim status As String = rdr.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(status)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Btw, HttpClient is a more modern client than WebRequest if you are using .Net 4.5 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Wow thanks. Ampersands! That's what I was looking for. I guess I prefer commas. Haha.